# how to create a #define DEBUG in c

Tags: c, debugging

I only want to call `printHex()` when I am debugging the program. If I set DEGUG as 1 will `printHex()` be called in the code below? and if I set it to be 0 will it not be called?

```
#define DEBUG 1


TI_PUTS("Attempting to retrieve data\r\n")
sendCommand(Cmddata, Buffrec, sizeof(Cmddata)); //send a retrieve data command
clk_sys_delay(TWOSECOND); //delay 1 sec

#ifdef DEBUG
printHex("Data received\r\n", recBuff, sizeof(recBuff)); //print out received hex data
#endif
```

Comment: Did you try it? `ifdef` means "if defined". So if you define `DEBUG` to any value then `printHex` will be called. If you don't want the print then comment out or remove the `#define`.

Comment: Ok, totally off topic, but... `clk_sys_delay(TWOSECOND); //delay 1 sec`? :)

Comment: If you have #define DEBUG, then #ifdef DEBUG will be true; and #ifndef DEBUG will be false.

Comment: @kaylum, ah thanks what should I use if I want to turn if on or off using 1 and 0? Instead of just commenting out `#define`.

Comment: [C preprocessor Conditionals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_4.html). Use `#if DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use #define DEBUG when debugging and use //#define DEBUG when not...

Or you can check DEBUG == 1, like

```
#if defined(DEBUG) && (DEBUG == 1)
 printHex("Data received\r\n", recBuff, sizeof(recBuff)); //print out received hex data
#endif
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I suggest also to consider using the macro `NDEBUG` instead of `DEBUG`, because that is what `assert()` uses.